# How to provider and store in next/react js app

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write test for my provider by using real store but I am getting error that

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')
```

Provider.tsx

```
"use client";
import { store } from "@lib/store/store";
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export const ReduxProviders = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
);
```

store.ts

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userSlice from "./user/user.slice";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  user: userSlice,
});

export const store = configureStore({ reducer });
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

provider.test.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../core/libs/store/store"; 
import { ReduxProviders } from "../provider"; 

describe("ReduxProviders", () => {
  it("renders children without crashing", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ReduxProviders>
          <div>Test Children</div>
        </ReduxProviders>
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(getByText("Test Children")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
I read that we should use actual store instead of mocking.

Even if I mock it I ma still getting error that

```
 console.error
    The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import { ReduxProviders } from "../provider"; // Update the path accordingly

const mockStore = configureStore([]);

describe("YourComponent", () => {
  it("renders component connected to Redux store", () => {
    const initialState = {
      user: {
        name: "John Doe",
        age: 30,
      },
    };
    const store = mockStore(initialState);

    const { getByText } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ReduxProviders>
            <div>Test</div>
        </ReduxProviders>
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(getByText("John Doe")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByText("Age: 30")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Next version is 13
React version is 18

Comment: Why do you have two redux providers?

Comment: I am wrapping Provider in ReduxProvider and using as       <body>
        <ReduxProviders>{children}</ReduxProviders>
      </body>

Comment: have you tried to remove one of the provider?

Comment: Yes, if I remove <ReduxProviders>than test gets passed but I don't get coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not properly configured this part:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  user: userSlice,
});
```

you should be passing a reducer but you are passing whole `slice`. in the `userSlice` file you should have

```
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

this should be passed to the `combineReducers`

```
// since it is default export
import UserReducer from "./path/userSlice";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  user: UserReducer,
});
```